# symfony functional test : change base url

Tags: symfony, phpunit

When i read symfony documentation https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html, they initialize the client with this command :

```
$client = static::createClient();
```

And they can do a request with a relative path

```
$client->request('GET', '/post/hello-world');
```

The problem in my project is that i got this url being generated : http://localhost/api/users but what i want is http://myproject.localhost/api/users

How can i change the base url depending on the environment i am going to launch tehe tests (besause in my test environment, i will have http://myproject.test/api/users

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to pass server info as second argument of the createClient method, as example:

```
$client = static::createClient(array(), array('HTTP_HOST' => 'localhost/myalias/app_dev.php')) ;
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 3):

Also you can try to set manually:

```
$client = static::createClient();
$client->setServerParameter('HTTP_HOST', 'myproject.localhost');
```